# \autoref showing subsection and subsubsection

Tags: sectioning, hyperref

I'm using the `\autoref` command from the `hyperref` package. I have the following code:

```
\subsection{Foo}
\label{ssec:bar}
This is the overview.

\subsubsection{Bar}
\label{sssec:bar}
This is the small part.

Later in the text, we refer to `\autoref{ssec:foo}` and `\autoref{sssec:bar}`.
```

After compiling, this shows the following text:

> **I.A. Foo**
>
> This is the overview.
>
> **I.A.1. Bar**
>
> This is the small part.
>
> Later in the text, we refer to subsection I.A. and subsubsection
>   I.A.1.

The problem I have with this is that `\autoref` is showing "subsection" and "subsubsection", when I'd rather it just show "section". Is there any way to override this in the `hyperref` package so it doesn't put any of the "subs" in there?

Answer (score 24, accepted):

The names are stored in macros `<counter>autorefname`. The following examples redefines them using the same meaning as `\sectionautorefname`:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[colorlinks]{hyperref}
\renewcommand*{\thesection}{\Roman{section}}
\renewcommand*{\thesubsection}{\thesection.\Alph{subsection}}

\let\subsectionautorefname\sectionautorefname
\let\subsubsectionautorefname\sectionautorefname

\begin{document}
\section{Section}
\subsection{Foo}
\label{ssec:foo}
This is the overview.

\subsubsection{Bar}
\label{sssec:bar}
This is the small part.

Later in the text, we refer to \autoref{ssec:foo} and \autoref{sssec:bar}.
\end{document}
```

> [image: Result]

Comment: @Heiko Oberdiek: It isn't working for me. I added \let\subsubsectionautorefname\subsectionautorefname and \let\subsubsubsectionautorefname\subsectionautorefname after calling hyperref but the outputs are still the same (Subsubsection and  Subsubsubsection should be just Subsection). What Am I missing?

Comment: @Claudia If you are using package `babel`: example for language `ngerman`: `\addto\extrasngerman{<autoref name definitions>}`

Comment: @Heiko Oberdiek:  I use babel for brazilian language. I am not sure how to add those definitions. Aren't they already set?

Comment: @Claudia If `babel` is loaded *before*  `hyperref`, then `hyperref` can detect the supported languages.

Comment: I personnaly use 
`\addto\extrasenglish{
 \renewcommand{\sectionautorefname}{Sect.}
 \let\subsectionautorefname\sectionautorefname
 \let\subsubsectionautorefname\sectionautorefname
}` and feel very happy with it!

Comment: @HeikoOberdiek 
How to do for chapters?

Comment: @x-rw Usually the same way, the counter for chapters is `chapter`.

Comment: @HeikoOberdiek I searched for this issue again 9 years later, and came across my own question. For clarification, what is the purpose of the `\renewcommand` lines in your example? The sections are renamed as desired, even without them.

Answer (score 5):

I personally prefer to rename `subsection` and `subsubsection` like this:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[colorlinks]{hyperref}
\renewcommand{\sectionautorefname}{Section}
\renewcommand{\subsectionautorefname}{Section}
\renewcommand{\subsubsectionautorefname}{Section}

\begin{document}

\section{Prologue}

We can refer to \autoref{sec:lorem}, \autoref{ssec:foo} and \autoref{sssec:bar}.

\section{Lorem}
\label{sec:lorem}

Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Vivamus consectetur.

\subsection{Foo}
\label{ssec:foo}

Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Vivamus vel.

\subsubsection{Bar}
\label{sssec:bar}

Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Pellentesque pulvinar.

\end{document}
```

> [image: Result]

Comment: Welcome to tex.sx.  If all are shown in cross references as "Section". why not combine them as "Sections 2, 2.1, ,,,"?

Comment: I wrote them one after the other just to show as an example what it looks like